# buttons on scaled and rotated stage in pixi js does not respond to touch events

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, interaction, google-assistant

I am working on a game with pixi js. to make the game look normalized on every screen,

im scaled the stage as follows

`this.scale=Math.max(this.viewWidth, this.viewWidth) / (2048 * this.ratio);`

and on orientation change I am rotating the whole stage.

now my problem is, if i have any buttons on stage, who ate at op or at right side of stage, they do not respond to any touch event. Please help im in a very big trouble.

I tried to use `mappositiontopoint` as well. but didn't understand how to correctly use here.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a set of transparent nodes which were not interactive and this is why my scaled and rotated stage was not taking input. now it worked for me